# Formatting string from resource in XML

Tags: android

I have a fragment with ViewModel and a string resource like this

`<string name="money_format">Money: %1$d</string>`

In ViewModel I have MutableLivaData `money`. How I can set in fragment's XMLfile a text property to `money_format` with parameter `Money` from `viewModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll look like this

```
android:text="@{@string/money_format(viewModel.money)}"
```